# How to pass base64 encoded content to sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, base64

Variable XFILEBASE64 has base64 encoded content and I want to replace some string with that base64 content.

Sure enough base64 is packed with special characters, and I've tried $'\001' as delimiter, still getting the error message. Any suggestions?

```
XFILEBASE64=`cat ./sample.xml | base64`
cat ./template.xml  | sed "s$'\001'<Doc>###%DOCDATA%###<\/Doc>$'\001'<Doc>${XFILEBASE64}<\/Doc>$'\001'g"
> sed: -e expression #1, char 256: unterminated `s' command
```

EDIT: Looks like problem has nothing to do with sed, it must be hidden in base64 operations.

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>testsdfasdfasdfasfasdfdasfdads</a>
```

To reproduce the problem:

```
foo=`base64 ./sample.xml`
echo $foo | base64 --decode

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<base64: invalid input
```

Comment: which OS and eventually LANG ? Unix are treating differently depending on OS and LANG value and sed is purely text (ASCII if i remember well) so those caracter tend to be interpreted as EOL. Also not every sed allow hexa encoding (octal seems more available )

Comment: OS is RHEL 7.1 and LANG en_US.UTF-8, I do not think Hex is a problem if I leave hexa delimiter and replace variable content with static string it is fine.

Comment: right, replying i understand more clearly that this is not a problem of special char inside variable or template file, and you just include the hex as separator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was in base64 encoding, -w 0 option of base64 did the trick.

```
cat ./sample.xml | base64 -w 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Base64 has only three special characters ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history)) - usually `+`, `/` and `=`. You can use for example `@`, , `&` or `;` with no problem.

Comment: tried with @ getting the same problem, I assume problem is somewhere in base64

Answer (score 3):

```
Tempo64="$( echo "${XFILEBASE64}" | sed 's/[\\&*./+!]/\\&/g' )"
sed "s!<Doc>###%DOCDATA%###</Doc>!<Doc>${Tempo64}</Doc>!g" ./template.xml
```

- should work and posix compliant

Comment: Second sed still complains about unterminated `s'

Comment: certainly an unescaped character in Tempo64 to add in first sed class. I forget `!` at least (corrected now).

Comment: do you have any "small" sample of  XFILEBASE64 that failed ? every test on my linux pass ? another lmimitation could be the size of the content. Which lenght is the content of XFILEBASE64 ?

Comment: When I was trying to reproduce the problem with scaled down document, noticed that encoding is not done correctly, it was throwing an invalid input error. I've disabled line wrapping with base64 -w 0 and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if multi line is needed, escape the *new line" by adding `;$ !s/$/\\/` in Tempo64 sed should solve the issue

Comment: tried it with Tempo64="$( echo "${xfilebase64}" | sed 's/[;$ !s/$/\\/]/\\&/g' )" it did not solved the problem. So far only working solution I've got is with base64 -w 0

Comment: why the `s/[;$ !` and `]` ? seems a bit strange or bad copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
sed "s$'\001'<Doc>###%DOCDATA%###<\/Doc>$'\001'<Doc>${XFILEBASE64}<\/Doc>$'\001'g"
```

should be written as

```
sed s$'\001'"<Doc>###%DOCDATA%###<\/Doc>"$'\001'"<Doc>${XFILEBASE64}<\/Doc>"$'\001'g
```

That's to say, `$'...'` in double quotes are not special.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to user52028778's comment as I had to do more reading to diagnose what the issue was. The problem is in the base64 command. The default base64 command includes line wraps after 76 characters for some linux distros. This is inserting a line termination into the sed command later when the variable is used causing it to fail.

`cat ./sample.xml | base64 --wrap=0`

https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64